# Unable to manage 80GB android code on gitlab

Tags: gitlab

i am confused about managing source code on gitlab
basically i followed the bellow steps to get android base source code

- /$ mkdir myandroid
- ~/$ cd myandroid
- ~/myandroid$ repo init -u git://github.com/boundarydevices/android-manifest.git -b boundary-imx-p9.0.0_1.0.0-ga
- ~/myandroid$ repo sync

after repo sync the size of myandroid folder is 74GB

Since i need to maintain/manage this base code in gitlab so that developers can work on it

so i did

- ~/myandroid$ git init
- ~/myandroid$ git add .
- ~/myandroid$ git commit -m 'Added uncompiled base code '
- ~/myandroid$ git remote add origin git@github.com:scotch-io/my-project.git
- ~/myandroid$ git push -u origin master

it showed 100% success but when i login to gitlab webpage

i see that only few files are pushed while i only all directories and few files are pushed to the git server but i do not see the contents of the directories rather i see the image in this link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NjxYr7tntg5Bcha-tTvVdggJ50pY78Mk

Now my question is

1. why the folder shows up with "@ " and the contents of the folder is empty or has another folder that shows "@ "
2. can some one guide me how to manage this android code of 80GB in my gitlab server is there something that i am doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome! The "@" things are submodules. See https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md#Element-remote

Answer (score -1):

To manage your code Git LFS will help you , however keeping large files is not recommended but the Gitlab way to handle large files is documented here 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/lfs/manage_large_binaries_with_git_lfs.html

Also have a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/lfs/manage_large_binaries_with_git_lfs.html#troubleshooting as this mentions issues that you might be facing.

You need to ask your administartor to enable LFS in Gitlab 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/lfs/lfs_administration.html

How to enable lFS on local system read https://about.gitlab.com/2017/01/30/getting-started-with-git-lfs-tutorial/